# Unable to echo a-z in two columns by Zsh

Tags: zsh

I need to print the following sequence for illustration purposes in two columns

```
a-z
```

which has alphabets from a to z such that they are in 13-character columns.

**How can you echo the characters from a to z into two columns?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better solutions exist, I'm sure, but I'll give it a shot:

```
$ echo "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | sed -e 's/\(.\)\(.\)/\1 \2\n/g'
a b
c d
e f
g h
i j
k l
m n
o p
q r
s t
u v
w x
y z
```

Comment: @Stephan: Thank you for your answer! I had a similar solution in mind. Regexes understand the command a-z. I still believe that there is a built-in way to expand the a-z.

Comment: I get the following output for your command: a bnc dne fng hni jnk lnm nno pnq rns tnu vnw xny zn. I uses Mac Leopard's sed.

Comment: @Masi, i suspect you missed a '\'... did you type? for i in {a..z}; do echo -n $i; done | sed -e 's/\\(.\\)\\(.\\)/\1 \2n/g'

Comment: @Masi, Try changing 's/\\(.\\)\\(.\\)/\1 \2n/g' to 's/\\(.\\)\\(.\\)/\1 \2\n/g'

Comment: @nik: I did not use the for-loop. --- No difference for your last code.

Answer (score 3):

Very nice Stephan,

How about avoiding to type **a** through **z** with a loop?

```
for i in {a..z}; do echo -n $i; done | sed -e 's/\(.\)\(.\)/\1 \2\n/g'
```

Comment: I get the following output: { an. .nz }n

Comment: Masi, either there are c/p issues, or you have a weird shell :P

Comment: @Stephan, I use the for loop on unix shell extensively and end up avoiding many short scripts -- the history (CTRL+R) works like a great script cache!

Comment: @Stephan: I get the following in Bash: a bnc dne fng hni jnk lnm nno pnq rns tnu vnw xny zn

Comment: I was about to suggest using Ruby, since I had forgotten about the {a..z} syntax in zsh.  Very nice.

Comment: Note that this requires zsh >= 5.0.6, cf. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219008/expanding-a-d-to-a-b-c-d-in-zsh

Answer (score 0):

Your question did not specify how to distribute the characters in the two coloumns, so here is an alternative answer:

```
prompt> paste <(echo "abcdefghijklm" | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' ) <(echo "nopqrstuvwxyz" | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g')
a       n
b       o
c       p
d       q
e       r
f       s
g       t
h       u
i       v
j       w
k       x
l       y
m       z

prompt>
```

Comment: `paste <(echo -e \\n{a-m}) <(echo -e \\n{n-z})` (you need `setopt braceccl`) (i know i'm 3 years late)